# How to insert a record using table?

Tags: controller, class, visualforce

I have a table of 3 rows and 3 columns in which the data I enter should be saved in the account object. But what I am facing is , only the 3rd row data is inserted not the first two.

**My controller code :**

```
public class accountcontroller {


    public account acc {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public accountcontroller() {
        acc = new account();
    }

    public PageReference insertNewItem() {

        insert acc;
        //reset public property for new insert
        acc = new account();

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="accountcontroller">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:dataTable value="{!acc}"   var="a" cellpadding="4" border="1" >
          <apex:column headervalue="Account name"  width="20">
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}"/><apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}"/><apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headervalue="Account site" width="20" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.site}"/><apex:inputField value="{!acc.site}"/><apex:inputField value="{!acc.site}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headervalue="Account phone" width="20" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.phone}"/><apex:inputField value="{!acc.phone}"/><apex:inputField value="{!acc.phone}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockButtons location="BOTTOM">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!insertNewItem}" value="save"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Please provide me a best solution. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

You should update your code with this:

```
<apex:page controller="accountcontroller">
 <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockSection >

        <apex:dataTable value="{!acc}"   var="a" cellpadding="4" border="1" rows="3">
                <apex:column headervalue="account name"  width="20">
                     <apex:inputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
                </apex:column>

                 <apex:column headervalue="account site" width="20" >
                        <apex:inputField value="{!a.site}"/>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column headervalue="account phone" width="20" >
                        <apex:inputField value="{!a.phone}"/> 
                  </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>

     <apex:pageBlockButtons location="BOTTOM">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!insertNewItem}" value="save"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

class:

```
public class accountcontroller{

 public list<account> acc{get;set;}

 public accountcontroller(){
    acc= new list<account>();
    for(integer i=0 ; i<3 ;i++){
      account ac = new account();
      acc.add(ac);
    }
 }

  public PageReference insertNewItem() {

          insert acc;

      acc= new list<account>();
      for(integer i=0 ; i<3 ;i++){
         account ac = new account();
         acc.add(ac);
    }
      return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: it is working fine ..thank you..but after clicking the submit button the data table row disappears.only the data table heading is available..further I cant insert data again..

Comment: see updated controller class .....